# Cannot send Audio files on WhatsApp

Tags: applications, 4.2-jelly-bean, whatsapp-messenger, audio, system-error

I just recorded an audio using an app on my phone, The audio file has an extension .WAV, but when I try sending it via WhatsApp, I get this error

[image]

> Failed to process audio, please try again later, If you keep seeing this message, please restart your phone

Things I tried so far:

1) I restarted 4 times

2) Updated Google Play Music and WhatsApp as given in [this](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/30080887) site

3) Cleared Data, Cache and restarted WhatsApp

But nothing seems to solve the problem

I have enough memory on the phone, I can successfully send instant voice messages, PDFs, pictures and videos and contacts, I have read that WhatsApp supports .WAV so I dont think its a problem with the audio format, the audio plays well in my phone, so the audio file isnt corrupt or anything,
I have a strong Internet connection too.

Surprisingly I did not find any info on this particular error on the internet, It would be great If someone could tell me what the problem is.

**Phone Details:**

Phone: Xperia L

Android version: 4.2.2 (JellyBean)

WhatsApp version: 2.16.207

Comment: [Date/Time problem?](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/20971773).  Maybe resetting would help

Comment: @beeshyams Date and time seem alright, If i'm not wrong WhatsApp would specifically open an error dialog asking the user to correct Date/Time, again thanks for your interest.

Comment: Have you tried sending other audio files (not recorded by the app you used for that)? Maybe that app puts some small errors into the WAV file that WhatsApp can't comprehend.

Comment: @ValentinKuhn just figured out that WhatsApp doesn't support WAV, I tried with a different app which can record audio in MP3 and WAV, the mp3 works.

Comment: you should add that as an answer and accept it, just so that the question does not stay unanswered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WhatsApp (at-least the version 2.16.207 on Android version: 4.2.2 - JellyBean) doesn't seem to support audio files with WAV extension, I tried sending an mp3 and it seems to  work fine

However I found that WhatsApp with a same version on Andriod 6.0.1 (Marshmallow) has no problems in sending WAV files

In any case you can always use a [WhatsApp File Sender](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=retrospect.aditya.whatzappfilecourierads&hl=en) as mentioned in [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/112481/179271) answer.